# Google map dont work

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this part of code, that should show pins on google map of certain locations.

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var map;
    var elevator;
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);

    var addresses = ['Sarajevo', 'Africa', 'Asia','North America','South America'];

    for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
        $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
            var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                icon: "http://i.imgur.com/DOd1sH3.png"
            });

        });
    }

});
```

```
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Map shows up and everything works, but the pins of locations are not shown.
I really dont know why.

Comment: Have you checked your console? What does it say?

Comment: What is the output console.log(data) in $.getJson

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P2QhE/3600/ i copy this fiddle here, it can not be that hard. Console says Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped.

Comment: I created a [fiddle from the posted code](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/mbg2yyaq/), it works for me (I see markers on a computer where imgur.com is not blocked).  [SitaReturn's fiddle works for me as well]

Comment: I also dont have problems with that fiddle when i try it online, but on my page markers do not show

Comment: Check the status of the request from your server, you may be running into a quota limit or permission issues, the Google Maps Geocoding Web service is not intended to be used from javascript, use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) instead.

Comment: It is working. Check your google js plugin path

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Centar%20Sarajevo,%20Bosnia%20and%20Herzegovina&sensor=false. (Reason: missing token 'x-csrf-token' in CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' from CORS preflight channel). Getting this error i am also using Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are calling the constructor without a reference to a variable.

Try this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latlng,
             map: map,
             icon: "http://i.imgur.com/D0d1sH3.png"
});
```

Alternatively you can set the markers to the map by calling the setMap function

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latlng,
             icon: "http://i.imgur.com/D0d1sH3.png"
});

marker.setMap(map);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: not rly, now my map is white when i add var marker :(

Comment: That's weird, your jsfiddle actually works for me, i'm seeing markers. What browser are you using?

Comment: it works i try it online jsfiddle.net/P2QhE/3600, but on mypage does not :( why?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe you should edit your question to include your full code and we could better understand what happen? I don't seem to be able to reproduce this issue. I copied the code to local machine and it works as well

Comment: i include 2 google apis, for some reason that was the problem. ty